# Real Analysis. Convergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've found that the sequence is bounded between the values 1.5 and 2 which is option (a), but since this is a recursive limit and bounded, solving the equation should give us option (d) as an answer as well. Why is that not the case? A quick help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkPBc.jpg

Comment: I'm not following your reasoning, but note that $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ is irrational, unlike $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in fact we have that $a_n > \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$ for all $n \geq 1.$ Indeed, this is clear for $n = 1$ and assuming it is true for a certain $n,$ we have that $a_{n + 1} = 2 - \frac{1}{1 + a_n} > \frac{4 + 2\sqrt{5}}{3 + \sqrt{5}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$ Another way to see the same thing is assuming that there is $n \geq 1$ such that $a_n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$ Then we have that $a_{n - 1} = \frac{a_n - 1}{2 - a_n} = \frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{3 - \sqrt{5}} = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2},$ so $a_1$ must have also been $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2},$ which is of course false.